# Create News Site Pages from CSV in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to migrate Announcements from Sharepoint 2013 into Sharepoint Online News Webpart.

I can get the old Announcements into a Excel file(CSV) with an simple export for the List in Sharepoint 2013.  I need to import these into Sharepiont Online as Site Pages that are then promoted to News items.

I have a few powershell commands that i think can accomplish this but i am having trouble putting it all together.  I am new to Sharepoint.

I found this code to create site pages

```
#Config Variable
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet"
  
#Connect to PpP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive # -Credentials (Get-Credential)
  
#Create new page
$Page = Add-PnPPage -Name "News" -LayoutType Article
 
#Set Page properties
Set-PnPPage -Identity $Page -Title "News" -CommentsEnabled:$False -HeaderType Default
 
#Add Section to the Page
Add-PnPPageSection -Page $Page -SectionTemplate OneColumn
 
#Add Text to Page
Add-PnPPageTextPart -Page $Page -Text "Welcome To News Portal" -Section 1 -Column 1

#Publish the page
$Page.Publish()
```

This code can be used to Promote it as a News item

```
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet"
 
#Connect to Site
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Get all Site pages - along with their IDs
Get-PnPListItem -List "SitePages"
 
#Demote News page with ID "4" to Site Page
Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Values @{"PromotedState"="2"}
```

How do i combine all this so that i can create News Site Pages from the CSV?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Import-Csv` to get site page properties in csv. Please refer to following code.

```
$PageNames = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\test.csv
foreach($PageName in $PageNames){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution I proposed?

If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.

Looking forward to your reply

Have a lucky day!

Thanks,
Raytheon Xie

Answer (score 0):

Building on Raytheon-Xie-MSFT answer, the code would look like this (if you can provide an example of the CSV file - what metadata you need to write, this can be refined to exactly write out the pages:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Ask the user for the Page input file 
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

$page_file_name = $FileBrowser.FileNames

if ( !$page_file_name){
    Write-Host 'No input file was selected, terminating script'
    exit # nothing to see here, an input file was not selected
}

$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet"
  
#Connect to PpP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive

# note: better to us tab delimited files since page names can include commas
$Pages= Import-Csv -Path $page_file_name

foreach($Page in $Pages){
 #Create new page
$Page = Add-PnPPage -Name "News" -LayoutType Article
 
#Set Page properties
Set-PnPPage -Identity $Page -Title "News" -CommentsEnabled:$False -HeaderType Default
 
#Add Section to the Page
Add-PnPPageSection -Page $Page -SectionTemplate OneColumn
 
#Add Text to Page
Add-PnPPageTextPart -Page $Page -Text "Welcome To News Portal" -Section 1 -Column 1

#Publish the page
$Page.Publish()
}

Get-PnPListItem -List "SitePages"
 
#Demote News page with ID "4" to Site Page
Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Values @{"PromotedState"="2"}
```